# Laravel: Model not working if I named it "Auth"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Why when I name my model `Auth` it not working at all? But when I change name to different model work correctly?

**Not working:**

```
<?php

class Auth extends Eloquent {

    public static function check()
    {
        return "working";
    }

}
```

**Working:**

```
<?php

class MyAuth extends Eloquent {

    public static function check()
    {
        return "working";
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, `Auth` is a predefined class in Laravel used for basic user authentication. I'm sure that Laravel doesn't like you trying to use it twice.

Comment: It should be noted that `Auth` isn't something that'd typically be a **model**.

Comment: @ceejayoz but it could be if it represented a table in a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel already has a built-in `Auth` class.

You could remove the line:

```
'Auth' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
```

from `app/config/app.php` if you're not using Laravel's built-in `Auth` class.

Answer (score 3):

`Auth` is a predefined class for user authorization in Laravel. To name a second class `Auth` too, you will need to put the new one in a different `Namespace`